# how to open excel file on a button click without OLEDB/Interop but using openxml/spreadshetlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, openxml, export-to-excel

I have a ASP.NET file upload controller which opens rtr,xls and xlsx file. need to browse the file and open it in a button click .

[image]

I am using  DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll  and SpreadsheetLight.dll

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {

                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                string Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + FileName));
                string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + FileName);
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filepath);
                switch (Extension)
                {
                    case "xls":
                        //do sometthing
                        break;
                    case "xlsx":
                        //do sometthing
                        break;
                    case "rtr":
                        //do sometthing
                        break;
                }


            }
        }
```

Comment: It is not at all clear to me what you want to do. Do you want to parse the file and display the contents to the user?

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the level of ambition in what you are trying to do. Reading values in an Excel spreadsheet (xlsx, openxml) is trivial - but getting graphs and rendering them, calculate references or even results of formulas in cells can be rather tricky.

For an example of how to read values in an OpenXml spreadsheet, see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh298534(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh298534%28v=office.15%29.aspx)